# Why can't I store a lambda function in a SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am playing with lambda in Visual C++ 11.

```
void CWin32Service::RunService (__in  DWORD dwArgc, __in  LPTSTR *lpszArgv)
{

auto SvcMainptr = [this](__in  DWORD dwArgc, __in  LPTSTR *lpszArgv) -> void    {ServiceMain(  dwArgc, lpszArgv );} ;


SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY DispatchTable[] = 
{ 
    { m_ServiceName, (LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION)SvcMainptr }, <<== Error HERE 
    { NULL, NULL } 
}; 
....
}
```

The error message I get is:

'type cast' : cannot convert from 'CWin32Service::RunService::<lambda_22F3FB7B8C044A64>' to 'LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTIONW'

Comment: Under the final C++11 spec, a lambda with an EMPTY capture specification can be treated like a regular function and assigned to a function pointer. Tanks for your help. By the way service main is a class member so it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a Win32 API that expects to take a real function pointer with an exact signature.  You can't pass a lambda or other type of function object to it.

You should be passing ServiceMain in the service dispatch table.

Comment: Tanks for your help. By the way service main is a class member so it won't work.